# Constraints Error while trying to add button as subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to put a simple button within the AVPlayerViewController (for my tvOS app) in the bottom left corner of the screen above the scrub bar.  I'm getting an error that indicates "Constraint items must each be a view or layout guide".

I don't have the positioning set correctly as I'm just trying to see if I can get the button to show up at all.  Can someone advise why this code is crashing?

```
- (void)setupBreakButton
{
    NSLog(@"**** In setupBreakButton....");
    UIButton* skipBreakButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
    skipBreakButton.backgroundColor = [[UIColor bm_colorWithHexString:@"64A6BD"] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0f];
    skipBreakButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    
    skipBreakButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    /* Leading space to superview */
    NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonXConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton.leadingAnchor attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeLeft multiplier:1.0 constant:30];
    /* Top space to superview Y*/
    NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonYConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                 constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton.topAnchor attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self attribute:
                                                 NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:258];
    /* Fixed width */
    NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton.widthAnchor
                                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                          toItem:nil
                                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                                        constant:35];
    /* Fixed Height */
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton.heightAnchor
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                           toItem:nil
                                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                       multiplier:1.0
                                                                         constant:12];
    /* 4. Add the constraints to button's superview*/
    
    [self.view addConstraints:@[leftButtonXConstraint, leftButtonYConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint]];
}
```

Also, how do I add this button as a subview of the AVPlayerViewController?

Comment: `constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton.leadingAnchor`. That's an anchor, right? The error says, that item MUST be a `UIView` or a `UILayoutGuide`, not an `NSLayoutAnchor`. Same for the other one with "Anchor". Remove the `.zzzAnchor`. You are already saying with `attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft` that's the `leadingAnchor`

Comment: @Larme I tried that, I'm still getting the following error:

Thread 1: Exception: "NSLayoutConstraint for <UIButton: 0x7fdbbaf4efb0; frame = (50 50; 200 200); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002c4c720>>: Constraint items must each be a view or layout guide."

Comment: `toItem:self`, self is a `UIViewController`, no? What you meant is `self.view`.

Comment: Try to set parameter `constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton`, not `skipBreakButton.leadingAnchor` or another one. And see Larme's comment too.

Comment: But how do you add it as a subview? 

[self.avPlayerViewController.contentOverlayView addSubview:skipBreakButton];  ??

Comment: See my answer. It works for me.

Comment: You did `[self.view addConstraints:@[...]`, with comment `/* 4. Add the constraints to button's superview*/`, so we can only guess that `skipBreakButton.superview` is `self.view`, no? So it should be okay then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your custom viewController call this method

```
UIButton* skipBreakButton;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@""];

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

[self addChildViewController:controller];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];

controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.width,UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds.size.height);
controller.player = player;
controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
[player play];

NSLog(@"**** In setupBreakButton....");

skipBreakButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 200)];
skipBreakButton.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0f];
skipBreakButton.layer.cornerRadius = 6;

[skipBreakButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventPrimaryActionTriggered];

[self.view addSubview: skipBreakButton];

skipBreakButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
/* Leading space to superview */
NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonXConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                             NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:30];
/* Top space to superview Y*/
NSLayoutConstraint *leftButtonYConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                             constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:
                                             NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:258];
/* Fixed width */
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                   relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                      toItem:nil
                                                                   attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                                    constant:35];
/* Fixed Height */
NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:skipBreakButton
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                       toItem:nil
                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                   multiplier:1.0
                                                                     constant:12];
/* 4. Add the constraints to button's superview*/

[self.view addConstraints:@[leftButtonXConstraint, leftButtonYConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint]];
}

- (NSArray<id<UIFocusEnvironment>> *)preferredFocusEnvironments {

return @[skipBreakButton];
}

-(void)didTapButton:(UIButton *) sender {
NSLog(@"didtapbutton");
}
```

Comment: I will test this out tomorrow morning and get back to you. I’m not sure if the button would work properly on tvOS. Specifically, I’m referring to the focus engine.

Comment: This solution works.  The button shows up.  However, I need this to work on tvOS and I'm unable to scroll and click on the button.  What do I need to do to get that to work?

Comment: Don’t we need to use focus guides? I want the button to be a smaller button that says “Skip Intro” right on top of the left most side of the seekbar. How does the application know how to handle swipe gestures on the remote without using a focus guide?

Comment: How did you check it?

Comment: I put your changes into my own code.  I can't even scroll to the button.

Comment: I don't use scrollView in my example. I can't reproduce your case.

Comment: I'm not using scrollView.. I'm simply saying that I can't scroll with the tvOS remote to the button itself.